# GCP: Cloud Scheduler job with target App Engine HTTP. Unable to secure connection to admin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I have created a Cloud Scheduler job with target to App Engine HTTP. The target URL is /admin/task/create-documents

I have an App Engine flexible running with java 8.

It works fine, but now I would like to secure the access to the servlet called by the Cloud Scheduler job (/admin/task/create-documents) to GCP developers only (usually referenced as 'admin'). I assumed the Cloud Scheduler job is considered as 'admin'.

Option 1 - didn't work

I tried to modify the web.xml file as for the standard environment, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#security-auth), but with no success:

The web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Option 2 - didn't work

I tried to modify the app.yaml by adding `login: admin` to the `handlers` section, as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#creating_jobs), but with no success either.

The app.yaml file:

```
runtime:    java
env:        flex
threadsafe: true

runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
  server: jetty9

handlers:
  - url: /admin/.*
    script: auto
    login: admin
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

env_variables:
  JETTY_ARGS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=WEB-INF/logging.properties

network:
  instance_tag: no-ip
  name: my-network
  subnetwork_name: my-subnet
```

But I also noticed that the login parameter is deprecated, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences#migrating_your_appyaml_file). They mention IAM policies but I'm not sure how I should configure them.

How do I secure the Cloud Scheduler job endpoint to 'admin' only?

Answer (score 1):

You can't by configuration. You need to implement the check in your code.

You can add a static value to the URL like `https://my-url.appspot.com/admin/task/create-documents?key=my_secret` or use OIDC authentication with Cloud Scheduler to provide a JWT token to your endpoint.

In both case, you will have to check if the secret (content on the JWT) is the expected one or not.